# Does the formula \$Av\times \left( v_{in-}-v_{in+}\right) \$ of opamp applies also for DC voltage input?

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

For a two-stage Miller op-amp, if I only apply DC common mode input, the vout is obviously not zero, since there is a voltage drop across M7.
So does this mean that the formula Av*(v_in_plus-v_in_minus) applies only for sinusoidal v_in_plus and v_in_minus? If this formula does apply for DC input, why am I not getting a zero vout when v_in_plus is equal to v_in_minus? Thank you.

Comment: 0 volts out must mean a volt-drop across M6 so, when you say "*vout is obviously not zero, since there is a voltage drop across M6*" you are misleading yourself.

Comment: @Andy aka, Sorry I am saying a voltage drop across M7

Comment: That's the same thing. There'll be a volt drop across both when 0 volts is at the output. Reason: you haven't specified Vdd or Vss and, for an op-amp analysis, it would be assumed that these are equally positive and negative hence, the default output voltage is 0 volts. This sort of question calls for precision in what you are saying.

Comment: I think you are assuming that Vss is 0V, right?

Comment: VSS is 0 in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula only applies to an ideal op-amp.

For a real op-amp, you should consider an offset voltage term:

$$v_{out}=A_v\left(v_+ - v_- + v_{offs}\right)$$

This is true for both AC and DC inputs.

For modern commercial op-amps the offset term might be in the microvolts to millivolts range. For a very simple design like the one you're studying it is probably in the high end of this range or even many millivolts.

The offset effect is often compensated for by using negative feedback in the application circuit (or within the op-amp itself in more complex designs than yours).

Comment: The term "offset" confuses me a lot. As I understand, offset might exist for various reasons. The first one is because of matching. But let's say my opamp is perfectly matched. Does offset still exist?

Comment: @Xiutao, it means the op-amp responds to the input as if it were offset (changed) by a fixed amount.